# sld parser for version 1.1.0 with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, sld

I am using Openlayers 2.11 and need to style a layer with a sld file version 1.1.0. the error it says is **Uncaught Can't find a SLD parser for version 1.1.0**. i have also tried it with Openlayers 2.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OpenLayers 2.13.1 does not parse 1.1.0 SLD- I get the same error as the OP when using a 1.1.0 SLD file for a GeoJSON layer. Fortunately I found a (sloppy) workaround via some find-and-replace magic in the SLD file:

1. Changed beginning of file (xml prologue is it called??) to match 1.0 standards:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <sld:StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
   xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">`
2. Changed all instances of `SvgParameter` to `CssParameter` (credit to the suggestion at the end of [this post](http://cartaro.org/blog/14-how-use-qgis-great-looking-symbols-cartaro)).
3. Changed all instances of `<se:whatever>stuff</se:whatever>` to `<sld:whatever>stuff</sld:whatever>` (this may have been just a QGIS feature, I am not sure).

Like I said, not pretty, but it allowed me to adapt a 1.1.0 SLD file exported from QGIS and then parse it in OpenLayers.

Answer (score 1):

Check OpenLayers 2.13 it might have a solutin

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. See accepted answer.